# How can I ammend the Exponent and Modulus functionality on this code to work?

Tags: java, eval, operator-precedence, modulus, exponent

first question here so I'm not entirely sure on the right way of going about this but here goes:

---

So, I was looking for some simple code to Evaluate dynamic string expressions and found this great code [here on Study.com](https://study.com/academy/answer/java-evaluate-expression-modify-listing-20-9-evaluateexpression-java-to-add-operators-for-exponent-and-for-modulus-for-example-3-2-is-9-and-3-2-is-1-the-operator-has-the-highest-pre.html) but for some reason the Exponent ^ and Modulus % operators aren't registering or working even when all the other 4 binary operators are working just fine.

So I'd appreciate if you guys could just take a look and offer some assistance on how I can modify it to work. Thanks in advance!

---

> A simple example would be: if you were to enter an operation such as
>   *String[] go = {"1^2"}* or *String[] go = {"1%2"}* at the start of the code and compile, it would automatically defer to *Wrong expression:
>   1^2* or *Wrong expression: 1%2* respectively.

---

Here's the code as is on [Study.com](https://study.com/academy/answer/java-evaluate-expression-modify-listing-20-9-evaluateexpression-java-to-add-operators-for-exponent-and-for-modulus-for-example-3-2-is-9-and-3-2-is-1-the-operator-has-the-highest-pre.html):

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    String[] go = {"1+2"};
    if (go.length != 1) {
    System.out.println("Usage: java EvaluateExpression \"expression\"");
    System.exit(1);
    }

    try {
    System.out.println(evaluateExpression(go[0]));
    }
    catch (Exception ex) {
    System.out.println("Wrong expression: " + go[0]);
    }
}

public static int evaluateExpression(String expression) {

    Stack<Integer> operandStack = new Stack<>();

    Stack<Character> operatorStack = new Stack<>();

    expression = insertBlanks(expression);

    String[] tokens = expression.split(" ");

    for (String token: tokens) {
    if (token.length() == 0) 
    continue;
    else if (token.charAt(0) == '+' || token.charAt(0) == '-') {

    while (!operatorStack.isEmpty() &&
    (operatorStack.peek() == '+' ||
    operatorStack.peek() == '-' ||
    operatorStack.peek() == '*' ||
    operatorStack.peek() == '^' ||
    operatorStack.peek() == '%' ||
    operatorStack.peek() == '/')) {
        processAnOperator(operandStack, operatorStack);
    }

    operatorStack.push(token.charAt(0));
    }
    else if (token.charAt(0) == '*' || token.charAt(0) == '/') {

    while (!operatorStack.isEmpty() &&
    (operatorStack.peek() == '*' ||
    operatorStack.peek() == '/')) {
    processAnOperator(operandStack, operatorStack);
    }

        operatorStack.push(token.charAt(0));
       }
       else if (token.trim().charAt(0) == '(') {
       operatorStack.push('(');
       }
       else if (token.trim().charAt(0) == ')') {

       while (operatorStack.peek() != '(') {
       processAnOperator(operandStack, operatorStack);
       }
       operatorStack.pop();
       }
       else {

       operandStack.push(new Integer(token));
       }
       }

       while (!operatorStack.isEmpty()) {
       processAnOperator(operandStack, operatorStack);
       }

       return operandStack.pop();
   }

   public static void processAnOperator(Stack<Integer> operandStack, Stack<Character> operatorStack) {
        char op = operatorStack.pop();
        int op1 = operandStack.pop();
        int op2 = operandStack.pop();
        if (op == '+') operandStack.push(op2 + op1);
        else if (op == '-') operandStack.push(op2 - op1);
        else if (op == '*') operandStack.push(op2 * op1);
        else if (op == '/') operandStack.push(op2 / op1);
        else if (op == '^') operandStack.push(op2 ^ op1);
        else if (op == '%') operandStack.push(op2 % op1);
}

public static String insertBlanks(String s) {
    String result = "";
    for (int i = 0; i < s.length(); i++) {
    if (s.charAt(i) == '(' || s.charAt(i) == ')' ||
    s.charAt(i) == '+' || s.charAt(i) == '-' || s.charAt(i) == '^' || s.charAt(i) == '%' ||
    s.charAt(i) == '*' || s.charAt(i) == '/')
    result += " " + s.charAt(i) + " ";
    else
    result += s.charAt(i);
    }
    return result;
}
```

Comment: I'm aware the code looks satisfactory but should you compile it while testing an expression featuring either of the two aforementioned operators (exponent or modulus) it automatically responds with ""Wrong expression: 'expression'".

Comment: If you look at the code (not that great IMO, kind of hard to read) inside the main `for`,  first `if` is handling `+` and `-`, second `*` and `/`; then comes parenthesis and last `else` just numbers - no `^` or `%` - these must be added (`%` having same precedence as `/` should be easy, `^` havin higher precedence requires an additional `else if`)

Comment: Thank you very much, Carlos. This really helped me debug the code and discover the omission that had to be reinstated. You were also correct about the additional else if.